# fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have source code of a Visual Studio C++ project. Project contains cpp and header files of the initial project. Those files are in different folder and subfolders. However the main function exists in the default directory. I want to create a new project and add the code.

However I don't know what exactly I've to do in order to build the project. Firstly I create a empty C++ project. The next step to add .cpp files and .h files. Should I add in the project stdafx files?  How can I add the code in subfolders in the new project?

EDIT:I follow instructions of TobiMcNamobi. I add existing items from solution project. Project build all files. However I am receiving an error:

```
 fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
```

What exactly this error mean? I have checked the following  [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/179230-fatal-error-lnk1561-entry-point-must-be-defined/), it says that maybe it is not clear if the new project is Win32 Project instead of a Console. However I have created an empty project? Should I turn into a Console project?

EDIT2: I add all the dependencies and all files. The problem now is that I am facing the following error:

error LNK2005: "public: static class cv::Mat __cdecl CmSaliencyRC... already defined in .obj

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is it *really* that you know how to add .cpp and .h files but you ask how to add those files from subfolders?

Comment: The fist question is clear, am I suppose to add stdafx.cpp and stdafx.h from the source code? The second one, I just have to add all .cpp  and .h files to project from all possible directories? As I said I ve created a new empty project and I try to add files in header files and source files folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a bit on *what you want* and *how much source code you have*.

Do you want to work on the project as a whole using Visual Studio? And the project is has many source files? Then I would put *every* .cpp and .h file of it into the VS project. Yes, stdafx.cpp and .h and *all* subdirectories.

Do you want something specific, a certain part of the project and you have just a few source files? Then you should start with only those files you *need* and add files when you see that they are required, too.

Adding files to a VS project is simple right clicking the project (in Solution Explorer), select "Add" / "Existing Item". A file chooser dialog appears, select all files you want to add from any subdirectory.

I admit that I *do not* know an elegant way to do this if you have a lot of directories.

Comment: It is actually a big project. I am not sure still what to add. I am not sure how to add the code which is in subfolders. Just add it to header and source folders?

Comment: OK I think I am near to solution, I just add with existing item everything. Elegant? Not! Only problem some links have problem. However I am think I am near to solution.

Comment: SegmentAllign.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl saliencyCut. What does this error could possible mean?

Comment: @FereRes Well, if you search this site for "unresolved external" or "LNK2019" you will find several answers (and discussions) about this. Anyway, it is barely in the scope of your original question.